# Regex sre_constants.error: bad character range

Tags: python, regex, json

I'm trying to a get a JSON string from another string with this regex:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback\((.*?)\)
```

It works on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rD1hI9/1), but when I use it in my code:

```
import re
import json
import requests

def stock_lookup(name):

    url = "http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query={0}&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback".format(name)

    response = requets.get(url)

    json_data = json.loads(re.match(data,"YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback\((.*?)\)"))


    return json_data
```

I get this error:

> sre_constants.error: bad character range

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced the arguments in the `match` method, regex should come first.

```
re.match("YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback\((.*?)\)", data)
```

[`re.match` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`

The error is shown because most probably there is some `z-A` type of range in the `data`.

Comment: Aahaha thanks a lot. I think i left my brain somewhere

Comment: Maybe you also code in C#, where `Regex.Match` accepts input string as the 1st argument, and the pattern as the 2nd. The issue is not so uncommon.

Comment: Not wrong, i just got the example from C# code even though ain't a C# Programmer.