# Apply list of regex pattern on list python

Tags: python, regex, list

I have data frame in which `txt` column contains a list. I want to clean the `txt` column using function clean_text().

```
data = {'value':['abc.txt', 'cda.txt'], 'txt':['[''2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart'']',
                                               '[''2019/02/01-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart'']']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)

def clean_text(text):
    """
    :param text:  it is the plain text
    :return: cleaned text
    """
    patterns = [r"^{53}",
                r"[A-Za-z]+[\d]+[\w]*|[\d]+[A-Za-z]+[\w]*",
                r"[-=/':,?${}\[\]-_()>.~" ";+]"]

    for p in patterns:
        text = re.sub(p, '', text)

    return text
```

*My Solution*:

```
df['txt'] = df['txt'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
```

But I am getting below error:
*Error*

```
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex sre\_constants.error: bad character range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797581/regex-sre-constants-error-bad-character-range)

Comment: @sophros, this question is different.

Comment: in what way it is different? The error is the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`^{53}` is not a valid regular expression, since the repeater `{53}` must be preceded by a character or a pattern that can be repeated. If you mean to make it validate a string that is at least 53 characters long you can use the following pattern instead:

```
^.{53}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have updated question, now I get `Attribute error`.

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is the first pattern from the list - `r"^{53}"`. It reads: `^` - match the beginning of the string and then `{53}` repeat the previous character or group 53 times. Wait... but there is no other character than `^` which cannot be repeated! Indeed. Add a char that you want to match 53 repetitions of. Or, escape the sequence `{53}` if you want to match it verbatim, e.g. using [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have updated question, now I get `Attribute error`.

Comment: This should really be another question. How a reader of the question can make any sense of the answers if you change the crucial elements of the question?

Comment: And before you do that - please revert the change first so that the answers make sense with the question.

Comment: I have post it as different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620550/getting-error-while-using-apply-on-a-list-python. Can you please help me in solving.

Comment: I have already done that although I believe you should reward the effort already made on answering this question.