# Getting error while using apply on a list python

Tags: python, regex, list, dataframe

I have data frame in which `txt` column contains a list. I want to clean the `txt` column using function clean_text().

```
data = {'value':['abc.txt', 'cda.txt'], 'txt':['['2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart']',
                                               '['2019/02/01-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart']']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data)
    df
 value    txt
 abc.txt  ['2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart']
 cda.txt  ['2019/02/01-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart']
def clean_text(text):
    """
    :param text:  it is the plain text
    :return: cleaned text
    """
    patterns = [r"^.{53}",
                r"[A-Za-z]+[\d]+[\w]*|[\d]+[A-Za-z]+[\w]*",
                r"[-=/':,?${}\[\]-_()>.~" ";+]"]

    for p in patterns:
        text = re.sub(p, '', text)

    return text
```

*My Solution*:

```
df['txt'] = df['txt'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
```

But I am getting below error:
*Error*

```
df['txt'] = df['txt'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'



clean_text(df['txt'][1]
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I am not sure how to use `numpy.where` in this problem.

Comment: It's different. How can I use `np.where` in my case?

Comment: I take it your data-set in this example is incomplete? When running your code with the provided value for `data`, this runs fine for me and does not produce an attribute error.

Comment: @SpencerD, I have updated question, basically txt column contains a list of string.

Comment: Ah that makes a bit more sense, although, the code above obviously is malformed, due to where you pasted the output of `df` at. Anyway, not sure what your end-goal is for the data, but this does seem to run and does perform replacements `df['txt'].apply(lambda x: [clean_text(z) for z in x])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the revision to your question, and discussion in the comments, I believe you need to use the following line:

```
df['txt'] = df['txt'].apply(lambda x: [clean_text(z) for z in x])
```

In this approach, `apply` is used with `lambda` to loop each element of the `txt` series, while a simple for-loop (expressed using Python's list comprehension) is utilized to iterate over each item in the `txt` sub-list.

I have tested that snippet with the following value for `data`:

```
data = {
    'value': [
        'abc.txt',
        'cda.txt',
    ],
    'txt':[
        [
            '2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart',
        ],
        [
            '2019/02/01-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC704     asfasnfs: remove datepart',
        ],
    ]
}
```

Here is a snippet of console output showing the dataframe before and after transformation:

```
>>> df

     value                                                txt
0  abc.txt  [2019/01/31-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC...
1  cda.txt  [2019/02/01-11:56:23.288258 1886     7F0ED4CDC...

>>> df['txt'] = df['txt'].apply(lambda x: [clean_text(z) for z in x])

>>> df

     value                         txt
0  abc.txt  [asfasnfs remove datepart]
1  cda.txt  [asfasnfs remove datepart]
>>>
```

Comment: @user15051990 I will never understand why people accept answers but don't also up vote them. It's of course totally optional, but it doesn't cost anything. (currently the only up vote is mine)

Comment: @uhoh, lol I cannot pretend to understand, but oh well. Glad to be of help to someone! 